# OpenLayers 3 - Z-index of features on highlights

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have some troubles with z-index on OpenLayers 3 when i want to highlight a feature.

I create a GeoJSON shape of a country, add some marker on top, and i want the shape color change when i hover on.

But, when the color change, the shape hide my markers.

I try to put zIndex style on the hightlight style but this doesn't change anything...

```
    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })],
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }),
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [631965.84, 4918890.2],
            zoom: 3
        })
    });

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({}),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            zIndex: 1,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#589CA9',
                width: 3
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#589CA9'
            })
        })
    });

    map.addLayer(vector);

    var selectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#EF7F01',
                width: 3

            }),
            zIndex: 1,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#EF7F01'
            })
        })
    });

    map.addInteraction(selectPointerMove);

    var feature = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeature(Some_GeoJSON_Coordinate, {
        dataProjection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'),
        featureProjection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')
    });

    vector.getSource().addFeature(feature);

    iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([5, 44],"EPSG:4326", 'EPSG:3857')),
        type:"marker"
    });

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        zIndex:2,
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            anchor:[0.5,1],
            scale:0.1,
            src: 'https://lh4.ggpht.com/Tr5sntMif9qOPrKV_UVl7K8A_V3xQDgA7Sw_qweLUFlg76d_vGFA7q1xIKZ6IcmeGqg=w300'
        }))
    });

    iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

    vector.getSource().addFeature(iconFeature)
```

I create a JSFiddle of my issue : http://jsfiddle.net/a1zb5kzf/1/

Thanks you in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.

According to the [Select Interaction documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html), it's don't just apply an other Style but move your feature on a temporary overlay. And so, zIndex doesn't work because features aren't on the same layer anymore.

So, to get my highlight comportement and keep my feature on the same layer, i watch the **pointermove** event, and apply style if necessary. Just before, i memorized the feature, and reapply default style on it

```
 cartoCtrl.map.on("pointermove", function (evt) {
                    var feature = cartoCtrl.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
                        function (feature) {
                            return feature;
                        });
                    if (feature && feature.getProperties().type != "marker") {
                        cartoCtrl.lastHighlitedFeature = feature;
                        feature.setStyle(highlightStyle)
                        }));
                    } else {
                        if(cartoCtrl.lastHighlitedFeature){
                            cartoCtrl.lastHighlitedFeature.setStyle(defautlStyle);
                            cartoCtrl.lastHighlitedFeature = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is a better option if you want just highlight. It is also possible to add your icon feature to an `ol.FeatureOverlay` and keep using select interaction.